# Multiple variadic argument lists allowed?

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I am wondering if this kind of function is possible or not:

```
def func(*arg1, *arg2):
```

If yes then do let me know how we will identify which all arguments belong to `arg1` and which all belong to `arg2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this kind of function signature is not allowed in Python:

```
>>> def foo(*args1, *args2):
...
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's not allowed because of the problem you've already mentioned: not possible to identify how many arguments should belong to `*arg1` and how many to `*arg2`.